# android dependencies error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have developed the game using buildbox which i have done before. at this time I am not able to export my project to apk due to this error-

(Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/neerajmahawar/Desktop/(angel game studio)/santa_2/android/libs/playhaven/bin/playhaven android sdk.jar'    com.angel.santa     Build path  Build Path Problem.

I tried everything at my best. cleaned project many times but no changes found. 
please help me to get rid of this problem.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you ever tried to remove and import the library again?

Comment: Ok, try removing the library again but this time, Right click to your project, select Properties, select Android in the menu on leftside and At the bottom part there is an add button. Click it and select your library folder. Then select the project. Check the "is Library" option. Then add.

Comment: one thing i found is buildbox is not exporting jar file for my recent update in game. in the old version i had the jar developed in to bin folder. I am checking it why its happening. will let you know if that works..

Comment: I tired both but did not work.. Also the buildbox is generating the libs/playhaven/bin/playhaven android sdk.jar. THe process i am doing is. importing the files to eclipse then i am having some error or src and gen which i solved by cleaning the project. but after cleaning eclipse is deleting the android sdk.jar from the folder. I dont know why.